# Обработчик нажатия вызывает зависание

Tags: jquery, javascript, firebug

Есть 2 файла:

index.php:

```
<TABLE border="1">
<TR>
<TD>1</TD>
<TD>2</TD>
<TD>3</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>4</TD>
<TD>5</TD>
<TD>6</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

javascript.js:

```
function createBlock(){
  var block = document.createElement('div');
  block.className = 'overlay';
  block.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1><p>Close</p>';
  document.body.appendChild(block);
}

$("td").click(function(){    
  createBlock();
}

$(".overlay p").click(function(){
  alert("Done");
  $('div.overlay').remove();
});
```

При нажатии на `close` `Firefox` зависает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Spectre, можете ваш комментарий преобразовать в ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".overlay p").click` навешивает обработчики на уже существующие элементы DOM выбраные селектором, в вашем случае лучше воспользоваться [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем live ???

```
jQuery("td").click(function(event){   
    if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "p" && jQuery("#mydiv").length == 0) {
        jQuery("body").append("<div id='mydiv'>");
        jQuery("#mydiv").html("<h1>Hello</h1><p>Close</p>").click(function() { 
                jQuery(this).remove()
            });;
    } 
});
```

Comment: click по всему окошку будет его закрывать - замечательно

Comment: А что мешает подкорректировать вот это : 
"event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "p" ? 

Я всего-то привел пример. P.S. По себе знаю, что live() - не самый лучший выход. Таких слушателей лучше не добавлять... хотя, как правило, это особо и не нужно.

Comment: да, раньше это было не лучшим выходом, но в последних версиях разработчики оптимизировали этот метод:
[пруф](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/131884/), читаем ``Улучшена производительность делегированных событий (Delegated Events)``